# Using a key on different maps

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

Are there any potential issues that could arise from using a Key on different maps as follows.

```
Map<Key, Value> employeeBasicInfo= new HashMap<>(); 
Map<Key, Value> employeeDetailInfo = new HashMap<>(); 

....
//EDIT: Lets assume this is a unique key where every department has unique employee names. 
 String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Smith";
String department = "IT";
Key employeeKey = new Key(firstName, lastName, department );

Value employeeBasicInfo = new Value(salary,grade,dateHired....);

Value employeeDetail = new Value(performanceEvaluation,benefit,familyInfo,...);

employeeBasicInfo.put(employeeKey, employeeBasicInfo);
employeeDetailInfo.put(employeeKey, employeeDetail);
```

**NOTE**:The key is used twice with `employeeBasicInfo` and `employeeDetailInfo`

Assuming the key above will be unique(no two people will have the name John Smith in the same department), is this considered as a bad programming practice, if so what are the reasons?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that if there are 2 John Smith from IT you would get a problem. Maybe if you have a unique id for each employee would be safer. But this is a functional problem, not technical

Comment: I agree, this is just a simple example I could come-up with. The Key is unique in the actual case.

Comment: Beside, we are not planning to hire another John Smith in our IT department any time soon :)

Comment: You just reject people who happens to have the same name?

Comment: @JimmyT. Not really,I was just making fun of my own poor example :)

Comment: @user624558 Racist what's wrong with J. Smith? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay to have one key point to two pieces of data, but the data structure for it feels wrong - you have to maintain two separate maps, and if the data in one is mutated, then you've lost the key forever.

You shouldn't mutate the key, but what you can do is store them in one data structure:  a [`Multimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained).  It's part of Guava's suite.

```
final Multimap<Key, Value> employeeInfo = ArrayListMultimap.create();
employeeInfo.put(employeeKey, employeeBasicInfo);
employeeInfo.put(employeeKey, employeeDetail);
```

What this gives you is equivalent (in a sense) to a `Map<Key, Collection<Value>>`, and since you know the order in which you put these elements in, retrieval is straightforward.

```
Value basicInfo = ((List<Value) employeeInfo.get(employeeKey)).get(0);
Value detail = ((List<Value>) employeeInfo.get(employeeKey)).get(1);
```

You have to perform the cast, since `Collection` has no notion of a `get(int index)`.

Comment: Interesting solution. I wonder if the get and put methods have a constant-time complexity similar to a `HashMap`

Comment: Seems like it would; retrieval from a map is constant, and retrieval from a list with index is constant.

Comment: This would work better than keeping two maps, the only problem is I am planning to keep one of the maps as a cache and reset the other one after processing the data. The API doesn't show a way to remove only one of the values from the `MultiMap`.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly valid to use the same Key on different maps (as long as you don't mutate the key value). Using the same value is fine too (as long as you don't mutate it). For example, I might use a "name" to index a person's address and their date of birth in two maps.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is very common to have the same key in diffrent maps. There is no problem with that.

In your specific example you have name and department as key but at least the department could change. In that case the map would not work. I can't see why you even need the map in the first place.